# why grep '\s*' is not working, but grep '\S*' works

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I am new to shell script.
I want to display the line starts with whitespace or non-whitespace in the file, but `grep '\S*'` works, `grep '\s*'` does not match any line.
And `'\s'` looks works
My grep version is 3.4. I am using WSL Ubuntu. The read color means it is matched. I tried [[:space:]], the result is same
Anyone can help? Thanks

test.fa includes

```
ctatccagcaccagatagcatcattttactttcaagcctagaaattgcac
 haha
 
   ok
acttgtatataaaccaaccgaagatgaggattgagagttcatcttggtgg
```

running result

[image]

Comment: `\s*` and `\S*` both match the empty string, so both should match *every* line. Are you sure your version of `grep` supports either?

Comment: `\s` isn't guaranteed to be supported by POSIX-standard grep at all. Use `[[:space:]]` instead. And instead of `\S`, use `[^[:space:]]` -- that way you aren't depending on OS-specific extensions.

Comment: Also, don't show code as screenshots. Copy-and-paste it into your question **as text**. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: You say that `grep '\s*'` doesn't match anything, but your second output shows that it matches everything.

Comment: Get rid of the `*` because it matches an empty string.

Comment: Do you have an alias for `grep`?  Both `^\S*` and `\^s*` *are* correctly matching every line, though the resulting colorization of matched non-space strings in your image cannot be explained by `grep` alone.

Comment: ...one-or-more is generally more sensible than zero-or-more, so you typically will want `+` instead of `*`. But since if you have one-or-more of something you also necessarily have one of that thing, why use any modifier at all?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You say "I want to display the line starts with whitespace or non-whitespace in the file." So if the line start with whitespace, then you want to display it. And if it starts with non-whitespace, then you want to display it. Isn't that "any non-blank line"?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Even with `[^[:space:]]`,  wouldn't we need extended regular expressions ( `-E`)?

Comment: @user1934428 @user1934428 no, `[:space:]` is a character class that means `any white space` in any POSIX tool regardless of the RE type they're using.

Answer (score 1):

`*` means "zero or more repetitions of the preceding expression". So `\S*` matches zero or more non-spaces while `\s*` matches zero or more spaces, and puting a `^` in front means match those at the start of a line (when the string being compared is a line as is the case with `grep` by default).

So in your input file:

```
Line 1: ctatccagcaccagatagcatcattttactttcaagcctagaaattgcac
Line 2:  haha
Line 3: 
Line 4:   ok
Line 5: acttgtatataaaccaaccgaagatgaggattgagagttcatcttggtgg
```

`^\S*` matches the following on each line:

```
line 1: ctatccagcaccagatagcatcattttactttcaagcctagaaattgcac
Line 2: the null string before the leading blank
Line 3: the null string that is the whole line
Line 4: the null string before the leading blanks
Line 5: acttgtatataaaccaaccgaagatgaggattgagagttcatcttggtgg
```

while `^\s*` matches the following on each line:

```
line 1: the null string before ctatccagcaccagatagcatcattttactttcaagcctagaaattgcac
Line 2: the leading blank
Line 3: the null string that is the whole line
Line 4: the leading blanks
Line 5: the null string before acttgtatataaaccaaccgaagatgaggattgagagttcatcttggtgg
```

So both regexps match something on every line, and what is colored as matching is the printable (i.e. non-null and non-blank) chars from each matching string.

To display the lines that start with whitespace would be:

```
grep '^\s'
```

and to display the lines that start with non-whitespace would be:

```
grep '^\S'
```

and to display empty lines would be:

```
grep -v '.'
```

If your grep doesn't support `\s/\S` then use `[[:space:]]/[^[:space:]]` instead if it's a POSIX grep or `[ \t]/[^ \t]` in any grep.

Comment: Thanks, so ^\S* and ^\s* can match null string if there are no other matching strings?

Comment: @Miracle regexp comparisons match the leftmost-longest string in the input so it's not really that they "can match null string if there are no other matching strings", it's simply that they **do match** 0 or more occurrences of the preceding expression (\S or \s) and so 0 matches is every bit as valid as 1 or more matches.

Comment: @Miracls Try `echo "abc" | grep 'y'` and of course you get no output because there isn't a `y` in the input. Now try `echo "abc" | grep 'y*'` and you do get output because with `y*` you asked to find 0-or-more `y`s in the input and there are in face 0 `y`s in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton : For `\s` to work in this way, wouldn't we have to use `-P` to make this feature available?

Comment: @user1934428 no, `\s` is just a (typically GNU) tool extension that means `[[:space:]]` regardless of the RE type they're using.

Comment: @user1934428 `\s` _is_ formally a PCRE feature, but some implementations (indeed, GNU included) add it to other RE types as well, even though the standard doesn't call for it. I don't know of any implementations that support `-P` and _don't_ add `\s` to non-PCRE implementations (indeed, GNU grep compiled without libpcre won't support `-P`, but will still support `\s`; caveat: I'm not 100% sure if it's using a regex engine provided by grep itself or from the libc -- in the latter case, this may be an OS-specific behavior).